# If cell value starts with text, then populate another column - App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cannot get `startsWith` to work in App Script. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
function test(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
        if(data[n][0].toString().startsWith('ABC-')=='ABC-'){
      data[n][16] = 'ABC'
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

### Issue:

- [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) returns either **true** or **false**, therefore `==` is wrong because now you compare a boolean with a string.

### Solution:

**Replace:**

```
if(data[n][0].toString().startsWith('ABC-')=='ABC-')
```

**with:**

```
if(data[n][0].toString().startsWith('ABC-'))
```

### Script - Output:

**Script**:

```
function test(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
        if(data[n][0].toString().startsWith('ABC-')){
      data[n][16] = 'ABC'
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you soMarios, unfortunately that does not update my Google sheet when testing.

Comment: that's a different question. Use `sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)` assuming `data` is symmetrical.